# Truffle Pet Shop Parse Error

Tags: solidity, truffle

I keep getting an error when I try "truffle compile" on the truffle pet shop tutorial. Here is my code

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Adoption {
  address[16] public adopters;

  function adopt(uint petId) public returns (uint) {
    require(petId >= 0 && petId <= 15);

    adopters[petId] = msg.sender;

    return petId;
  }

  function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
    return adopters;
  }

}
```

and this is my error

```
project:/contracts/Adoption.sol:1:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
Adoption.sol
^------^
```

Comment: can u run: solc --version to get back the version i suspect the main problem is the compiler version

Comment: where do I run that command?

Comment: on your terminal

Comment: i've got solc 0.8.7

Comment: try pragma ^0.8.0 instead of 0.5.0

Comment: I still get this project:/contracts/Adoption.sol:1:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
Adoption.sol
^------^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.4.11 (core: 5.4.11)
Node v14.17.6

Comment: Have you try compile the fille with solc insted of truffle? if you can compile it that mean you either setup truffle wrong or something is wrong with your truffle

Comment: I will re-install truffle and see how it goes. It compiles appropriately with remix

Comment: I re-installed an older version of truffle but now I get this error with the same code. /Users/kliffordhawkins/pet-shop-tutorial/contracts/Adoption.sol:16:33: ParserError: Expected token LBrace got 'View'
  function getAdopters() public view returns (address[16] memory) {
                                ^

Comment: it worked when I re-installed the updated truffle version